# Read data from excel and store them in the list. (Vb.net)

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have an excel sheet having 2 columns. Now i want that all values of column 1 should be stored in one list lets say ListTime and all values of column 2 should be stored in another list lets say ListAcceleration. I dont know how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

> 

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6888f2b7-8893-4977-81b1-5d011af2a0e4/import-excel-to-vb-net-using-listview) helps you.

Comment: Why two separates lists?

Comment: @MaciejLos just like this..
Dim ListTime as new list(of Double)
Dim ListAcc as New list(of Double)

Now ListTime should contain all values from column 1 and ListAcc should contain all values from column 2

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but i ask you why 2 lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a good way:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
Public NotInheritable Class FormMain
    Private xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Private xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Private ListTime As New List(Of Double)
    Private ListAcceleration As New List(Of Double)
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        Dim Path As String
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "Exceldatei auswählen"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Excel", ".xlsx"))
            OFD1.IsFolderPicker = False
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            If OFD1.ShowDialog = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Path = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path)
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Tabelle1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
        Dim xlRange As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

        Dim ER As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

        For rCnt As Integer = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count Step 1
            ER = CType(xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
            ListTime.Add(CDbl(ER.Value))
            ER = CType(xlRange.Cells(rCnt, 2), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
            ListAcceleration.Add(CDbl(ER.Value))
        Next


        xlWorkBook.Save()
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        If xlWorkSheet IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet)
        If xlWorkBook IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
        If xlApp IsNot Nothing Then System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
        xlApp = Nothing
        xlWorkBook = Nothing
        xlWorkSheet = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub FormMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If xlWorkBook IsNot Nothing Then xlWorkBook.Close()
        If xlApp IsNot Nothing Then xlApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

There are just a few things you need to consider: First you have to download the “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel” package from Visual Studio's own NuGet package manager. Also the package “Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs” to have a reasonable OpenFileDialog.

[image: download Excel package in Visual Studio's NuGet]

[image: download OpenFileDialog package in Visual Studio's NuGet]

In the case of MS Office files, it is important to release the file using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(..)`, otherwise you cannot edit it later when you click it on your desktop. In that case you would have to restart the PC. So don't forget.

Oh and by the way: This word – in my case “Tabelle1” – will be named differently in your language. You have to change this.
[image: the name Tabelle]